# Image file not uploading to folder in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

I'm creating a form to upload profile picture with preview and upload it into a folder. I'm getting a preview of uploaded image but the file is not uploaded into folder. Am i doing it the right way or correct me if i'm wrong

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="avatar-upload">
            <div class="avatar-edit">
                <input type='file' id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
                <label for="imageUpload"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="avatar-preview">
                <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(Resources/Images/user.png);"> // user.png is a default picture
                <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="image_profile" value="">
                    <button type="submit" name="" style="display: none;">
                </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function readURL(input) {                 // IMAGE UPLOAD
        var image;
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
                $('#imagePreview').hide();
                $('#imagePreview').fadeIn(650);

                image=e.target.result;

            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            console.log( $('#imagePreview').html() );

            $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'upload.php',
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        data:{'image': image},

                        success:function(html) {
                            alert(image);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
    $("#imageUpload").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

// upload.php

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'upload/');
$image = $_POST['image'];
$image = str_replace('data:upload/jpeg;base64,', '', $image);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$data = base64_decode($image);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniq id() . '.jpeg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "upload/". $_FILES["image"]["name"] );
```

?>

I really appreciate for your help in advance :)

Comment: use $_FILES['image], instead of $_POST['image'].

Comment: The reader is asynchronous. The ajax call most likely executed before the readers `onload` method get's called. Do some debugging. Add some console logs to check in which order things gets executed. Also, check in your browsers network tab what actually get's sent.

Comment: @rawathemant - The OP is posting the file as a base64 encoded string, not as FormData. (Which also means that `processData: false,` isn't really needed)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm sure it will work

Comment: @rawathemant - The OP is _not_ posting a file. The OP is posting a _string_. Where that string came from or the fact that it contains base64 encoded file content is irrelevant.